# Google maps api geocode web service return an address with a dot added

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I call the geocode web service as:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=viale+carlo+felice+roma&sensor=false.
Its response is "Viale Carlo Felice., 00185 Roma, Italia" with a dot to end, why?
Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the database Google was registered this way, possible error

https://maps.google.com.br/maps?q=Viale+Carlo+Felice+Roma

see in bing/maps, it's different

http://br.bing.com/maps/#JndoZXJlMT1WaWFsZStDYXJsbytGZWxpY2UlMmMrMDAxODUrUm9tZStSTSZiYj00MS44OTEyNjk3MTc1NzA3JTdlMTIuNTE4NDkxNzUzMDI0MyU3ZTQxLjg4MzU0NDI4MjQyOTMlN2UxMi41MDQ2NTYyNDY5NzU3

Comment: I had thought but I wanted to get confirmation.
Thank you for your help.